# what is difference in ethereum transaction after constatanople upgrade?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan, constantinople

I have heard that Constantinople update transverse the consensus protocol of ethereum from proof of work to proof of stake. So they claimed that this update could speed up the TPS(transaction per second).if the above update is working.how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Ethereum network is still 100% Proof-of-Work. Proof-of-Stake will only be introduced in *Casper* update - still unsure when that will happen. Some plans (https://blockexplorer.com/news/ethereum-scaling-roadmap-casper-plasma-sharding/) indicate middle of this year but I somehow doubt that.

The *Constantinople* upgrade was mostly a minor upgrade to prepare for future upgrades (such as Casper). The biggest notable change is the reduction of mining reward from 3 ETH to 2 ETH. So there is no direct effect on TPS with this upgrade.